# Online Tutorials and Books for Learning Parsing

Tags: parsing

HI I am a Parsing Newbie and I intend to learn it for my project. Can anyone suggest me good books or tutorials for the same? I know a little bit about Context free grammar but that is all the exposure I have

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to learn parsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925774/best-way-to-learn-parsing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book teachs many things, including parsing. It's considered a classic in compilers.

[http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201100886](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886)